# Calling component method from @connect decorator (React/Redux)

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am new to React and Redux and I have a possibly very simple question that I can't seem to figure out: I have the following `@connect` decorator for one of my components:

```js
@connect((store) => {
  let options = store.helpers.options || [];
  let optionsRender = options.map((option, index) => {
    return (
      <div className="opt" data-slug={option.name} key={index} onClick={(e) => this.onOptionSelect(option.name)}>{option.name}</div>
    )
  });

  return {
    options: options,
    optionsRender: optionsRender
  }
})
```

I am rendering the `optionsRender` object inside my component, but I want to add an onclick handler to each of the generated divs. That handler is a method inside of my component, but how do I appropriately call that method if I am generating the object from the `@connect` decorator?

Comment: `connect` method is for getting data from state, not generating react elements. You should generate items inside your React component, in this case you will have access to the method you need and will place rendering of react components in the place where it belongs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `optionsRender` must be a part of the component and not the `connect mapStateToProps` definition. Connect must only handle the data and actions and not the render logic

```
@connect((store) => {
  let options = store.helpers.options || [];
  return {
    options: options
  }
})
class App extends React.Component {
   onOptionSelect = (option) => {
      // do things here
   }
   render() {
     return (
          <div>
             {this.props.options.map((option, index) => {
                 return (
                    <div className="opt" data-slug={option.name} key={index} onClick={(e) => this.onOptionSelect(option.name)}>
                        {option.name}
                     </div>
                  )
             })}
          </div>
     )
   }
}
```

Comment: In this case, where would the definition of `onOptionSelect` go? I have it inside the component, but I get a _onMedSelect is not defined_ error on the equivalent of line 6 of your answer.

Comment: It's still not being called somehow... The code makes 100% sense, but the onclick is just not being triggered.

Comment: what do you mean onClick is not triggered??

Comment: I am clicking on those elements that are generated and nothing happens. I have a `console.log()` within the `onOptionSelect` method and I don't see the output on my Chrome console.

Comment: So it turns out I had another method interfering with `onOptionSelect` and that's why it wasn't being called. Your answer is right after solving this new issue, so I will accept it.

Comment: Glad it helped :)